# How to interact with html response from http request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-apps-script, httprequest, httpresponse, service-accounts

I have a Flutter app where I am running a Google Apps Script through an http request. The purpose of the script is to create a Form and link the responses to a spreadsheetID that is passed in. The script is configured to only allow Google accounts access it and I've set up the flutter app to use a Service Account to access the script using the format:

```
getCredentials().then( (AuthClient client){
    response = client.get(url, headers{"Authorization": "Bearer ${client.access_token}");
});
```

**Issue:** The issue is that the first time that the Service Account makes a request it will get an HTML response saying that it the account needs to give permission to the script to access its data and I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm fairly new to making http requests and using it with the GoogleAPI so I'm stuck. Any advice?

Comment: Also, is it bad practice to create a document under your own credentials and change the ownership?

Comment: I don't believe you can use service accounts with the Apps Script API [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute). Can you share more of your code? Can you also expand a little on why you want to use a service account for this? There are ways to do this without them, but maybe you have a special reason for using them. Also, is the spreadsheetID is passed in from the client-side? Is your apps script project deployed in any way or are you running it as yourself?

Comment: You can't use the Apps Script API directly but you are able to make http requests to an App Script that has been deployed as a WebApp (which is what I'm doing). Also this app is meant to be one that is simple to use and also setup by anyone with a Google account with no background in tech. And from what I could find only the service account fit my requirements since I believe its the only credentials where anyone can simply create and use it without any other requirements like verification or a domain

Comment: Also the spreadsheetID is passed in with the url as a parameter. Btw, which code are you referring to and is there any particular part you would like for me to expand on?

Comment: If you have deployed it as a web app with minimal permissions, then anyone can make a request to it. You can make a request from some client-side JavaScript without any authentication needed. This bypasses any need for a service account, unless I am missing something. Is your app a tool for data-entry? In which case you would need the app to have permissions to operate on _their_ spreadsheets? Spreadsheets which you may not have access to, right? If so, then they would need to authenticate, there is no way around that. Service accounts only really work within domains.

Comment: The need for the service account (or credentials in general) is because the script is creating a Form for them and then assigning their Sheet as the destination for the Form responses. What I am hoping for a way to authenticate through http request or run the request (with its credentials) in flutter using something like url_launcher so that the user can authorize it

Comment: But I am also open to a workaround that has the same functionality as assigning a Form to the user running the script and setting their spreadsheetID as the destination

Answer (score 0):

#### Goal

*Create a web page which anyone can use to submit a Google sheet link and for the app to create a form and link the sheet to that.*

#### Authorization

For this users will require a google account and they will be required to go through the OAuth process to authorize your app.

To create the form and link it from client-side JavaScript you would indeed need to call the Apps Script API, though **you cannot do this with a service account**.

From: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute

> *Warning*: The Apps Script API doesn't work with service accounts.

Luckily, you don't need a service account to do this.

#### Instructions

- Create an Apps Script project with a function something like:

  ```js
  function createForm(ssID){
    form = FormApp.create("Your New Form");
    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ssID);
    let formLink = form.getPublishedUrl();
    return formLink;
  }
  ```
- Save and take a note of the ID of the script project.
- Set up a GCP project (sounds like you already have one).
- Make sure the Apps Script API is enabled in your GCP.
- Configure the OAuth consent screen and add the scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.
- Create an API key and a Client ID - add http://localhost:8000 or whatever port you are testing on to the "Authorized JavaScript Origins"
- Create OAuth credentials "web browser (JavaScript)".
- Link your Apps Script project to the same GCP project - [Instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- Deploy the Apps Script project as an API executable - take not of the **deployment ID**, although the documentation says that you need the script ID, it is wrong, at least with the new Apps Script IDE.
- Write the client-side JavaScript in your app like what is found in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js). Which will enable users to authorize the app. You need to add in the scopes and keys there too. I recommend just following the quick start steps first to get a feel for it. You can use the authorization parts without modification.
- Then add in the function that will call your Apps Script, something like this:

  ```js
  function appsScriptCreateForm(ssId) {
    var scriptId = "<DEPLOYMENT_ID>";

    // Run your Apps Script function
    gapi.client.script.scripts
    .run({
        scriptId: scriptId,
        resource: {
            function: "createForm",
            parameters: [ssId],
        },
    })
    .then(function (resp) {
        var result = resp.result;

        // ERROR HANDLING
        if (result.error && result.error.status) {
            appendPre("Error calling API:");
            appendPre(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        } else if (result.error) {
            var error = result.error.details[0];
            appendPre("Script error message: " + error.errorMessage);
            if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {
                appendPre("Script error stacktrace:");
                for (var i = 0; i < error.scriptStackTraceElements.length; i++) {
                    var trace = error.scriptStackTraceElements[i];
                    appendPre("\t" + trace.function + ":" + trace.lineNumber);
                }
            }

        // IF SUCCESSFUL
        } else {
            console.log("success", resp);
        }
    });
  }
  ```
- Write your HTML with the buttons and inputs necessary.
- Add event listeners where appropriate.
- Profit!

#### Please note

- This set up is *your* project running with the authorization of *other* accounts.
- The API requests count against *your* quota.
- You can see details of all the executions in your GCP Project Dashboard.
- Users require a Google account and need to authorize the app.
- In the Apps Script function above, you just need to pass in the Spreadsheet ID. Not the whole link. You could ask for the whole link and then use Regex to extract the ID if you wanted.
- This can be quite tricky and easy to miss a step or make a mistake, so double check your work.
- If, after successful authorization, when trying to run the script you get a 404 error, the request has been built wrong, check your IDs. If you get a 500 error, that can mean that the Apps Script function has successfully been called, *but*, there was an error *within Apps Script* and failed, check the executions page of the Apps Script editor.

#### References

- [Apps Script How to Execute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)
- [Apps Script JS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js) - Highly recommended you follow these steps first and get that working!
- [How to link your Apps Script to GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)

Comment: Where does this "whitelisting" come in? I don't see it in the Auth screen

Comment: Sorry, its when you create the Client ID - the "authorized JavaScript Origins"

Comment: Just for clarification, with this implementation the dynamic Google account making this call will be the one receiving this Form and having access to the Sheet, correct? The answer to this isn't  obvious with my current understanding of how all these pieces work together

Comment: If by receiving the form you mean is the owner of the form then yes. The sheet is created beforehand and you pass in the sheet document id, so they would presumably be the owner. The app basically creates a form and links it to the passed in sheet _on behalf_ of the account that is using it.